# Runtime error when using a parameter's methods

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm currently experiencing an error when trying to use a parameter object's methods.

What I'm trying to do:

```
USING class.Bar.
CLASS class.Foo SERIALIZABLE INHERITS Progress.Lang.Object:  
DEFINE PRIVATE VARIABLE cRrk_ID AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

  CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Foo(INPUT objBar AS Bar):
    THIS-OBJECT:cRrk_ID = objBar:getRrk_ID(). //Runtime Error: Invalid Handle (3135)
  END.
END.

CLASS class.Bar SERIALIZABLE INHERITS Progress.Lang.Object:
  DEFINE PRIVATE VARIABLE cRrk_ID AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

  CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Bar(INPUT pcRrk_ID AS CHARACTER):
    THIS-OBJECT:cRrk_ID = pcRrk_ID.
  END.

  METHOD PUBLIC CHARACTER getRrk_ID():
    RETURN THIS-OBJECT:cRrk_ID.
  END METHOD.
END.
```

Can someone explain why I can't use an Object's method when it's a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use but create Bar object and send to Foo's constructor:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE objBar AS "class.Bar"     NO-UNDO.

objBar = NEW "class.Bar"("hi").

DEF VARIABLE objFoo AS "class.Foo" NO-UNDO.

objFoo = NEW "class.Foo"(objBar).
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to NEW class.Bar first in class.Foo's constructor.

```
  CONSTRUCTOR PUBLIC Foo(INPUT objBar AS Bar):
    objBar = NEW class.Bar () .
    THIS-OBJECT:cRrk_ID = objBar:getRrk_ID(). //Runtime Error: Invalid Handle (3135)
  END.
```

Comment: But what if Bar's Constructor has fields which foo doesn't know of?
I only want to create Foo using the instance of Bar.

If I try to do NEW Bar(). it says err. 2680